# Is it possible to write an if statement within the return of a functional component? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to toggle a few lines of code when a popup is open. I've setup the constant and button onClick, but I'm not sure if it's possible to write something like an if statement to do such a thing.

I have tried to encapsulate the code in a single line if statement, but it clashes with the other inline code (the lastDroppedItem() section).

Reason I want to toggle it is because the code below overlaps on the popup modal that's invoked within the code in Button.jsx that sits above it in the return statement.

```
const Frame = ({ accept, lastDroppedItem, onDrop }) =>  {
  const [frame] = useState(pictureFrame);
  const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop({
      accept,
      drop: onDrop,
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isOver: monitor.isOver(),
        canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
      })
  })
  const [popup, setPopup] = useState(false);

   const isActive = isOver && canDrop

   return(
        <div className="content"  ref={drop} >
          {lastDroppedItem && ( <div className="animatedBox"><Button onClick={ () => setPopup(true) } selectedIcon={lastDroppedItem.type}/></div> )}
          <img className="frame" alt="main frame" src={frame} />

           //starting here I want to toggle the below
          {lastDroppedItem && (
            <img className="selectedIcon content" alt={ lastDroppedItem.type + " icon"} src={setIcon(lastDroppedItem.type)} />
          )}
          <div className="animatedBox">{isActive ? <Pill text={"Drop icon into picture frame!"}/>:
            <Pill text={"Drag icons on the left into picture frame!"}/> }</div>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Frame;
```

repo: https://github.com/WinsomeYuen/Artescence

Comment: It looks like you've already got the fundamentals there? You can use a `&&` to conditionally render one item (like you do for `lastDroppedItem`, or you use can a ternery (the ? : syntax) to render one thing if true, or another if false, like you do with `isActive`. Was there something specific you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Josh Hunt, ternary operator may do what you want.  Based on the condition, you can choose to render different block code.

```
return(
    // ...

    //starting here I want to toggle the below
    {lastDroppedItem /*or other condition*/ ? 
              (
                <img className="selectedIcon content" alt={ lastDroppedItem.type + " icon"} src={setIcon(lastDroppedItem.type)} />
              )
    :
              (
                <div className="animatedBox">{isActive ? <Pill text={"Drop icon into picture frame!"}/>:
                     <Pill text={"Drag icons on the left into picture frame!"}/> }</div>
                </div>
             )

)
```

Comment: Completely forgot about adding additional conditions to achieve this! 

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ternary operator together with helper function returning your pills. It is a bit more readable:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {useDrop} from 'react-dnd';
import setIcon from '../Option/setIcon.jsx';
import Pill from '../Pill/Pill.jsx';
import Button from '../Button/Button.jsx';
import './Frame.css';
import pictureFrame from '../assets/picture-frame.png';

const Frame = ({accept, lastDroppedItem, onDrop}) => {
    const [frame] = useState(pictureFrame);
    const [
        {
            isOver,
            canDrop
        },
        drop] = useDrop({
        accept,
        drop: onDrop,
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: monitor.isOver(),
            canDrop: monitor.canDrop()
        })
    })
    const [popup,
        setPopup] = useState(false);

    const isActive = isOver && canDrop
    const renderPillTags = (isActive) => {
        return <div className="animatedBox">{isActive
                ? <Pill text="Drop icon into picture frame!"/>
                : <Pill text="Drag icons on the left into picture frame!"/>}
        </div>
    }
    return (

        <div className="content" ref={drop}>
            {lastDroppedItem
                ? <div className="animatedBox"><Button onClick={() => setPopup(true)} selectedIcon={lastDroppedItem.type}/></div>
                : null}

            <img className="frame" alt="main frame" src={frame}/>
            {lastDroppedItem
                ? <img
                        className="selectedIcon content"
                        alt={lastDroppedItem.type + " icon"}
                        src={setIcon(lastDroppedItem.type)}/>
                : renderPillTags(isActive)}
        </div>
    );

}

export default Frame;
```